# Bold font not appearing when exporting Word file to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, truetype-fonts

I am using CMU Serif font in Word, but when saving as a PDF, the bold text shows up as regular.
I have checked and I have properly installed CMU Serif Bold so unsure what to do.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I suppose you have installed the TTF versions of CMU Serif, right? The Word PDF export [doesn't support embedding OTF fonts](https://superuser.com/q/1379789/176568) at all

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have installed "CMU Serif Bold" font on your computer.

When you choose the style of the word, DO NOT just make it bold, you have to change the font name from "CMU Serif" to "CMU Serif Bold" (if you can't find this "CMU Serif Bold" font in the drop down menu, you can type it).

Then save the word as pdf, Your pdf should display bold font correctly now, this solved my issue.

Comment: I tried the suggested workaround, but it didn't work for me. Word shows a "this font is not installed" warning when entering "CMU Serif Bold" - but the exported PDF is exactly the same.

Comment: It's hard to say if this worked for me. I got it working in the end, but I'm unsure if it was attributed to me installing more/different versions of CMU Serif or explicitly changing the name to CMU Serif Bold, as the UI doesn't really distinguish or display a CMU Serif Bold very well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this problem by modifying the CMUSerif-Bold TTF (cmunbx.ttf), so that it installs as a separate font family.

For this, I uninstalled the font, changed its font family to "CMU Serif BoldOnly" and installed it again. Then I selected "CMU Serif BoldOnly" as font in Word, which resulted the the correct font on screen and in the PDF export.

I used a TTF editor to change the (two) "font family" properties of cmunbx.ttf. I just got [TTFEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ttfedit/) for this, which requires Java but other than that no installation.

---

No clue though why this workaround is necessary. Probably just [yet](https://superuser.com/q/1379789/176568) [another](https://superuser.com/q/1709965/176568) [bug](https://superuser.com/q/1604706/176568) in Word's PDF export feature. For me, the PDF export feature was the [only one](https://superuser.com/q/1496802/176568) that worked for me because I wanted to get my embedded SVGs as vector graphics in the PDF. "Print to PDF" rasterizes the graphics...

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue when exporting files to PDF using CMU Serif downloaded from official page. Fortunatelly good guy have already forked official cm-unicode repo and did a fix for font weight.

check this on GH: https://github.com/Binjohn/cm-unicode-msofix

after installing those windows is recognizing weight properly and save as PDF works fine. Font name is the same so dont need to change anything in your word documents